# Processing a property in linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

It's my first LINQ TO SQL Project , So definitely my question could be naive .

Till now I used to create new property in Business Object beside of every DateTime Property   , That's because i need to do some processing in my DateTime property and show it in special string format for binding to UI Controls .Like :

`private DateTime _insertDate;
/// 
/// I have "InertDate" field in my Table on Database
/// 
public DateTime InsertDate
{
    get { return _insertDate; }
    set { _insertDate = value; }
}`

// Because i need to do some processing I create  a readonly string property that pass InsertDate to Utility method and return special string Date
public string PInsertDate
{
    get { return Utility.ToSpecialDate(_insertDate); }
}

My question is I don't know how to do it in LINQ . I did like follow but i get run time error. "Method 'System.String ToSpecialDate(System.Object)' has no supported translation to SQL"

`ToosDataContext db = new ToosDataContext();
var newslist = from p in db.News
               select new {p.NewsId,p.Title,tarikh =MD.Utility.ToSpecialDate( p.ReleaseDate)};`

GridView1.DataSource = newslist;
GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: What error did you get? Whenever you ask a question when you've received an error, *please* post what the error is.

Comment: it would be useful to post what error did you receive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate out the query performed in the database from the processing to be done in process. Try this:

```
var newslist = db.News
                 // First do a select in SQL
                 .Select(p => new {p.NewsId, p.Title, p.ReleaseDate})
                 .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest in process
                 .Select(p => new {p.NewsId, p.Title, 
                         tarikh = MD.Utility.ToSpecialDate(p.ReleaseDate) });
```